# Woocommerce Shortcode custom orderby not working

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, shortcode

I try to order product by custom meta like this:

in function.php added:

```
    add_filter('woocommerce_shortcode_products_query','add_shortcode_orderby_options', 10, 2); 
function add_shortcode_orderby_options ($args, $atts)
    {
        if ($atts['orderby'] == "distance") {
            $args['orderby']  = 'meta_value';
            $args['meta_key'] = 'current_distance';
        }
        return $args;
    }
```

and in my class:

```
echo do_shortcode('[products ids="' . $id . '" per_page="36" columns="4" orderby="distance" order="ASC" ]');
```

On my database I'v  meta_key and meta_value:

[image: in my database I'v]
But result are not ordered...

Any clue?

Thanks

EDIT:

Tried wit other method:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_orderby' );

                                $id = implode(",", $tmp);
                                echo do_shortcode('[products ids='.$id.' orderby="current_distance" order="ASC"]');

function woocommerce_shortcode_products_orderby( $args )
{
    $standard_array = array('menu_order','title','date','rand','id');
    if( isset( $args['orderby'] ) && !in_array( $args['orderby'], $standard_array ) )
    {
        $args['meta_key'] = $args['orderby'];
        $args['orderby']  = 'meta_value_num';
        $args['order']  = 'ASC';
    }
    return $args;
}
```

But now this remove some product from view...
If I have 7 product only 2 viewed, It's a pain, realy, just for sorted num and not string !

Help :-)

EDIT 2

Another try, now only first product sorted appear:

```
echo do_shortcode('[products ids='.$id.' per_page="16" columns="4" orderby="current_distance" order="ASC" pagination="true"]');

function woocommerce_shortcode_products_orderby( $args )
{
    $standard_array = array('menu_order','title','date','rand','id');
    if( isset( $args['orderby'] ) && !in_array( $args['orderby'], $standard_array ) )
    {
        $args['posts_per_page'] = -1;
        $args ['operator'] = "IN";
        $args['ignore_sticky_posts'] = false;
        $args['meta_key'] = 'current_distance';
        $args['orderby']  = 'meta_value_num';
        $args['order']  = 'ASC';
    }
    var_dump($args);

    return $args;
}
```

The dump are correct I'v 2 product but only one appear:

```
array(13) { ["post_type"]=> string(7) "product" ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["ignore_sticky_posts"]=> bool(false) ["no_found_rows"]=> bool(true) ["orderby"]=> string(14) "meta_value_num" ["order"]=> string(3) "ASC" ["posts_per_page"]=> int(-1) ["meta_query"]=> array(0) { } ["tax_query"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["taxonomy"]=> string(18) "product_visibility" ["field"]=> string(16) "term_taxonomy_id" ["terms"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(7) } ["operator"]=> string(6) "NOT IN" } } ["post__in"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "626044" [1]=> string(6) "528294" } ["paged"]=> int(1) ["operator"]=> string(2) "IN" ["meta_key"]=> string(16) "current_distance" }
```

Comment: A function can only have one "return" statement. The second "return" will never called.

Comment: Hi, yes already deleted the last return, keep just $args but same problem, ordered not works